# Как определить количество колонок в df

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = []
for x in range(3):
    if x == 0:
        for y in ['a','b']:
            cols.append((x,y))
    if x == 1:
        for y in ['a','c']:
            cols.append((x,y))
    if x == 2:
        for y in ['a']:
            cols.append((x,y))

cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(cols)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(), index=[x for x in range(10)], columns=cols)

df
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

Как вычеслить количество колонок `[0,1,2]` в МультиИндексном `df`

Я могу получить количество колонок `[a,b,a,c,a]`

```
len(df.columns)
```

**Output:** `5`

Но как получть количество колонок `[0,1,2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас мультииндекс. Вы можете получить к нему доступ, обратившись к нужному уровню:

```
df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

> Int64Index([0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype='int64')

```
print(set(df.columns.get_level_values(0)))
```

> {0, 1, 2}

ну и, соответственно, длину сета:

```
print(len(set(df.columns.get_level_values(0))))
```

> 3